# Javascript muestra alerta undefined

Tags: javascript, html

No estoy muy diestro con javascript por lo que decidí hacer un curso online desde cero y me pusieron como ejercicio realizar un juego de piedra papel o tijeras, por lo que lo realicé pero quise agregarle html para que el usuario pudiera insertar la opción de su preferencia y la variable viaja bien, es recibida por javascript e interpretada, si le pido que me arroje los resultados a través de un console.log lo hace sin problemas pero si decido cambiar el console.log de la función jugar() por un alert, el alert por el contrario solo me arroja undefined. Me gustaría poder mostrar el resultado del juego o de la función jugar() en html ya sea a través de una alerta o de un texto. A continuación el código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS NAME</title>
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script>
 var userInput = null;
function sub(){    
userInput = document.getElementsByName("prod")[0].value;
userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

function getComputerChoice(){
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
 //console.log(randomNumber);
  switch(randomNumber){
    case 0:
      return 'piedra';
    
    case 1:
      return 'papel';
   
    case 2:
      return 'tijeras';
   
    default:
      return 'error';
 
  }
}
var computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
/*console.log('Computadoraasd: ' + computerChoice);
console.log('Usuarioasd: ' + userInput);*/

function determineWinner(){
  if(userInput === computerChoice){
    console.log('Empate');
  }else if(userInput==='piedra' && computerChoice==='papel'){
    console.log('Gana la computadora');
  }else if(userInput==='papel' && computerChoice==='piedra'){
   console.log('Gana el usuario');
 }else if(userInput==='papel' && computerChoice==='tijeras'){
   console.log('Gana la computadora');
  }else if(userInput==='tijeras' && computerChoice==='papel'){
   console.log('Gana el usuario');
  }else if(userInput==='tijeras' && computerChoice==='piedra'){
   console.log('Gana la computadora');
  }else if(userInput==='piedra' && computerChoice==='tijeras'){
   console.log('Gana el usuario');
  }else if(userInput==='bomba'){
    console.log('Gana el usuario con trampa');
  }else{
    console.log('No computado');
  }
}

function jugar(){
  console.log('Computador: ' + computerChoice);
  console.log('Usuario: ' + userInput);
  console.log(determineWinner(userInput, computerChoice));
  
}

 console.log(jugar()); 
  
}
</script>
 
</head>
<body>
<h2>Ejila su opción</h2>
    <form name="form" action="" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="prod">
    </form>
    <button onclick="sub()">enviar</button> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basado en tu situación aquí como podría ser trate de mantener tu código lo mas apegado al tuyo pero los podría mejorarse

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS NAME</title>
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script>
 var userInput = null;
function sub(){    
userInput = document.getElementsByName("prod")[0].value;
userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

function getComputerChoice(){
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
 //console.log(randomNumber);
  switch(randomNumber){
    case 0:
      return 'piedra';
    
    case 1:
      return 'papel';
   
    case 2:
      return 'tijeras';
   
    default:
      return 'error';
 
  }
}
var computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
/*console.log('Computadoraasd: ' + computerChoice);
console.log('Usuarioasd: ' + userInput);*/

function determineWinner(){
  if(userInput === computerChoice){
    return'Empate';
  }else if(userInput==='piedra' && computerChoice==='papel'){
    return'Gana la computadora';
  }else if(userInput==='papel' && computerChoice==='piedra'){
   return'Gana el usuario';
 }else if(userInput==='papel' && computerChoice==='tijeras'){
   return'Gana la computadora';
  }else if(userInput==='tijeras' && computerChoice==='papel'){
   return'Gana el usuario';
  }else if(userInput==='tijeras' && computerChoice==='piedra'){
   return'Gana la computadora';
  }else if(userInput==='piedra' && computerChoice==='tijeras'){
   return'Gana el usuario';
  }else if(userInput==='bomba'){
    return'Gana el usuario con trampa';
  }else{
    return'No computado';
  }
}

function jugar(modo){
 var resultados = 'Computador: ' + computerChoice;
    resultados+='\nUsuario: ' + userInput;
    resultados+='\n'+determineWinner(userInput, computerChoice);
       
   switch (modo){
     case 'consola':
         console.log(resultados);
        break;    
        case 'alerta':
         alert(resultados);
        break;
    }
    
}

 jugar('alerta');
  
}
</script>
 
</head>
<body>
<h2>Ejila su opción</h2>
    <form name="form" action="" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="prod">
    </form>
    <button onclick="sub()">enviar</button> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno el error es simple unicamente tiene que llama las funciones tal cual son y no dentro de console.log

Actualmente esta haciendo esto

> console.log(determineWinner(userInput, computerChoice));

Esto debe quedar asi

> determineWinner(userInput, computerChoice);

y esto

> console.log(jugar());

debe quedar asi

> jugar();

Aquí el código corregido

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS NAME</title>
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script>
 var userInput = null;
function sub(){    
userInput = document.getElementsByName("prod")[0].value;
userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

function getComputerChoice(){
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
 //console.log(randomNumber);
  switch(randomNumber){
    case 0:
      return 'piedra';
    
    case 1:
      return 'papel';
   
    case 2:
      return 'tijeras';
   
    default:
      return 'error';
 
  }
}
var computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
/*console.log('Computadoraasd: ' + computerChoice);
console.log('Usuarioasd: ' + userInput);*/

function determineWinner(){
  if(userInput === computerChoice){
    console.log('Empate');
  }else if(userInput==='piedra' && computerChoice==='papel'){
    console.log('Gana la computadora');
  }else if(userInput==='papel' && computerChoice==='piedra'){
   console.log('Gana el usuario');
 }else if(userInput==='papel' && computerChoice==='tijeras'){
   console.log('Gana la computadora');
  }else if(userInput==='tijeras' && computerChoice==='papel'){
   console.log('Gana el usuario');
  }else if(userInput==='tijeras' && computerChoice==='piedra'){
   console.log('Gana la computadora');
  }else if(userInput==='piedra' && computerChoice==='tijeras'){
   console.log('Gana el usuario');
  }else if(userInput==='bomba'){
    console.log('Gana el usuario con trampa');
  }else{
    console.log('No computado');
  }
}

function jugar(){
  console.log('Computador: ' + computerChoice);
  console.log('Usuario: ' + userInput);
  determineWinner(userInput, computerChoice);
  
}

 jugar();
  
}
</script>
 
</head>
<body>
<h2>Ejila su opción</h2>
    <form name="form" action="" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="prod">
    </form>
    <button onclick="sub()">enviar</button> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Ahora te explico porque los indefinidos bueno esas funciones no tiene ningún valor de retorno es vació por lo cual esta indefinido dicho valor y como le pides que imprima en cosola 2 funciones que no retornan valores entonces pues sale 2 veces undefined

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus sugerencias, queda anotadas. Y para que el resultado se muestre en un alerta o que lo pueda mostrar en html, como haría?

Comment: alert(): enlugar de console.log();

Comment: Lo que podrias hacer es lo siguiente que tus funciones no hagan console log, sino que retorne valores determineWinner que retorne valor
y luego hace una mision al final que haga la concatenacion de todo lo que deseas mostrar, se por consola o por alerta inclusive podrias escribir en el html lo valores

Comment: Los alert me arrojan undefined

Comment: He agregado una respuesta para que veas mas o menos a los que me referia